# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript

This sounds like a duplicate question but I've tried solutions from those questions. I'm still facing the issue. I've a boolean variable in the global space and I'm trying to set the value inside a method which is called after a POST request.

**TS**

```
import ...;
@Component({
    ...
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    ...
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  hasError: boolean = false; // <----------- this is the variable

  public dropped() {
      ...
          this.http
            .post(
              'http://localhost:8090/.../file-process/upload',
              formData,
              { headers: headers, responseType: 'json' }
            )
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError)) // <------- control will go here
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
              console.log('checking', res);
            });
        });
      } else {
        ...
      }
    }
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    this.hasError = true; // <--- Error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'hasError')
  }

}
```

But I'm getting this error:
[image]

After fixing this line:
`.pipe(catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)))`

I'm getting this:
[image]

Please pitch in.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the this context in javascript. You need to wrap your function call in a lambda like this:

```
.pipe(catchError(err => this.handleError(err)))
```

More specifically the `this` object in a function is dependent on how it is called. Arrow functions do have a different behaviour. More details are explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: This will have one argument missing right ?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I edited the answer :)

Comment: Or you could use `fn.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0):

This shows error because you are directly referring a method from a class which results in changing its context when calling that method.

Instead you can bind that handleError() method with `this` context like below.

```
import ...;
@Component({
        ...
    })
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    ...
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  hasError: boolean = false; // <----------- this is the variable

  public dropped() {
      ...
          this.http
            .post(
              'http://localhost:8090/.../file-process/upload',
              formData,
              { headers: headers, responseType: 'json' }
            )
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))) // <------- control will go here with binded this
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
              console.log('checking', res);
            });
        });
      } else {
        ...
      }
    }
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    this.hasError = true; // <--- Error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'hasError')
  }

}
```

Comment: Now the component is working fine but i'm still getting error in console: file-upload.component.ts:124 ERROR undefined

Comment: Can you provide more error details like what is undefined?

Comment: Added one screenshot in the question